# django-channels Connecting websocket to channel

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

How do I connect the Websocket client to the Django channel? I created a basic handler and a the router:

```
from channels.routing import route
def ws_message(message):
    print(message["text"])

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.receive", ws_message),
]
```

But when I try to connect a websocket client:

```
import websocket
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://127.0.0.1/")
```

it throws the following error:

> Handshake status 200

Comment: Have you added channels to installed apps and configured CHANNEL_LAYERS .. also add a connect handler ? add a ws_open function and accept the connection .. route("websocket.connect", ws_open) .. def ws_open(message): message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})  ..

Comment: @SajiXavier Sorry for the delay in response! I just tried it out and it didn't work. Is still shows a handshake error.

Comment: instead of using Django-channel you can also use channels lib for socket connection it is easier than Django-channel

Comment: Are you actually using Django Channels [https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html]? If yes, don't you need a consumer?